# How to access directories with flask

Tags: python, file, flask

So I am making a website that has different accounts stored under the accounts folder path so for example I have a account folder for Bob and an account for John under each folder they both have a `achivements.dat` file how can I access that file from bobs account meanwhile John is trying to access his own achivements.dat file without getting crossed or changing the entire os's system path?
Thank you all for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For bob :

```
 with open('/path_to_files/bob/achivements.dat', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inbob:
     ...do some awesomness for bob here...
```

For john :

```
 with open('/path_to_files/john/achivements.dat', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as injohn:
     ...do some awesomness for john here...
```

Of course this code can sit in 1 function and be called as needed with parameter for user specific path passed. For example :

```
def read_file(path_for_some_user):
    from os import path
    with open(path.join('path_for_some_user','achivements.dat'), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as injohn:
         ...do some awesomness for john here...
```

Comment: This isn't working because it only takes 1 argument and according to my output encoding is a invalid argument.

Comment: @user2649920 well, python 3 accepts encoding parameter, try without it if you are using python 2.x. Also what do you mean by "it only takes 1 argument". If you think about read_file method, it depends where you put it, if you put it and how you annotate it, if u put it in a class without annotation it should look like 'def read_file(self, path_for_some_user)', etc.

Comment: The one permitter thing was my mistake I left out a prances and my comma got read as a comma not a part of a string sorry about that. I will try it with python 3.X I am using 2.X sorry